# How to handle event Handler in jQuery 3.4.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

It shows two events at same time:

[image: It shows two events at same time]

jQuery Code:

```
 $('[data-trigger="dropdown"]').on('mouseenter', function(){
    var submenu=$(this).parent().find('.submenu');

    submenu.addClass('active');

  }
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="profile-menu"> 
    <li>
        <a class="profile-menu-trigger" data-trigger="dropdown" href="#">Logged in as User</a>
    </li> 
    <ul class="profile-submenu submenu ">
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Logout</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Options</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Circus</a></li>
    </ul> 
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.submenu{ 
    list-style: none; 
    padding: 0px; 
    border: 1px solid #aaa; 
    background: #fff; 
    margin-top: 30px; 
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
    width: 250px; 
    position: absolute; 
    right: 20px; 
    display: none; 
} 
.submenu.active{ display: block; }
```

This program should show the menu on top right corner when touch on "User Logged in" but it can't.

Comment: Could you please provide the code for the html menu? Maybe you do not access the html element properly

Comment: @AlexisPavlidis here it is:
  <ul class="profile-menu">
          <li ><a class="profile-menu-trigger" data-trigger="dropdown" href="#">Logged in as User</a></li>
          <ul class="profile-submenu submenu ">
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          <li>  <a href="#">Logout</a></li>
          <li>  <a href="#">Options</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Circus</a></li>
          </ul>

        </ul>

Css Layer:

Comment: CSS Layer:

.submenu{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 30px;
  box-shadow:  2px 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  display: none;
}
.submenu.active{
  display: block;
}

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the HTML there. Note that you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make it runnable.

Comment: I helped you with the edits and also formatted the code that you posted in the comments (You can always [edit] your own question if you need to change anything in it). Please note that you can't have a `UL` as a direct child of a `UL` - This is an invalid HTML